# Concatenate two different variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<?php
$str="3dollars"; 
$a=20; 
$a+=$str; 
print($a);
?>
```

How can be the Output of the above program is 23 ?

Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: [That code works](https://eval.in/448997)

Comment: @JohnConde He knows the code works, he's asking **WHY** it is outputting 23..

Comment: @JohnConde Exactly my point that is why I asked read the manual. It will clear his concepts regarding the basics and will always help him in longer run. It's for his own learning curve.

Comment: meet type juggling: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: `+` isn't concatenation in PHP, it's addition; to concatenate in PHP, use the `.` operator

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator will coerce the string into being an integer, so it will (internally) do something like this:

```
$str = "3dollars";
$a = 20;
$a += $str;
// $str = (int)"3dollars";
// $str = 3;
$a = 23;
```

What you want to do is use the 'concatenation' operator (`.`):

```
<?php
$str = "3dollars"; 
$a = 20; 
$a .= $str; 
print($a); // 203dollars
```

Answer (score 0):

It's taking "3dollars" as a number, getting $str = 3.

And when you echo, you add 20, to $str, so it prints 23 and $a = 23.

```
  <?php    $a += $str;
    print($a);
    it echo 23;   //$a=$a+$b;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str= (int) "3dollars"; 
$a=20; 
$a+=$str; 
print($a);
```

Use `(int)` to convert string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
    $a = 20;
    $str = "3dollars";
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

    $matches = $a + $matches[0][0];

    echo '<br> Value Is :'.$matches;
?>
```

> This will print **23** as Answer.

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) ) 
Value Is :23
```

[phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dhza-cdt4)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082290/concatenate-two-different-variable-in-php#comment53981004_33082290)